# react-native asking Android runtime permission

Tags: javascript, android, android-permissions, react-native

I'm trying to ask for Android permissions within my React Native app. I followed the official documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) and I get this runtime error (from the `react-native log-android`command) :

```
W ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA')
```

This is the code I actually have :

My import (generated by WebStorm) :

```
import * as PermissionsAndroid from "react-native";
```

The code that actually ask for the permission :

```
try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
            {
                'title': 'A title',
                'message': 'A message'
            }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work since it comes from the official documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short words: you should import a single member of `react-native` module. This will look like this:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
```

What causes the problem is your `import` syntax. In your example you are importing the whole `react-native` module as `PermissionAndroid` variable in your module. But as you see from my code line you need only a single member from the whole package.

As for me, it was really a good idea to try different ES6 import syntax in real world and to get used to them.

Comment: Ah I'm so dumb and tired and didn't see this one coming ! Yeah it works now, was actually a totally easy one, thanks